# why 'git status' in cloned repository check current branch against origin remote and not in repository that I create

Tags: git, git-status

When I clone a repository from [github](http://github.com)  or any other website 
and type: `git status` it checks the current branch for changes against origin remote and shows the message (before making any new commits) : `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.`

But in repositories that I create it doesn't check for changes also I tried to add a remote with the same name `origin` but this also did not work 
I also looked at the documentation `git help status` but there is no information about that.

so How I will make my repositories checks for changes against the origin remote whenever I use the command `git status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays that message because a clone creates a local branch master which automatically tracks the "remote tracking branch" origin/master.

You can see it with `git branch -avvv`.

See "[Git remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)"

[image: http://git-scm.com/figures/18333fig0322-tn.png]

But when you create a repo, even when you add a remote named '`origin`', your local master branch doesn't track anything yet.

For that, you would need:

```
git remote add origin /url/to/upstream/repo
git fetch origin
git branch -u origin/master master
```

(See "[Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286030/6309)")

*Then* `git status` would display a status regarding your local branch vs. your remote tracking branch.